# Обнулить requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так,что бы при нажатии на `stop` , а затем снова на `start` рост начался заново ,а не продолжился с предыдущего значения.

```
var globalID;
var rost=0;
function repeatOften() {

rost+=3;
  $("div").css("height",  rost + "px");
  globalID = requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);
}

$("#start").on("click", function() {

  globalID = requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);
});

$("#stop").on("click", function() {

  cancelAnimationFrame(globalID);
});
```

Пример https://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/w9bvpx4g/3/

Comment: `cancelAnimationFrame(globalID); rost=0;`

Comment: Точно,крутяк,спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#stop").on("click", function() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(globalID);
});
```

замени на

```
$("#stop").on("click", function() {
  rost=0;
  cancelAnimationFrame(globalID);
});
```